# I have a question on Calculating number of product variants with 4 attributes and each having a different number of choices

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I have a problem that might be cakewalk, still posting it here.

We sell a wide range of LED lighting products with a lot of variants for each product. While we're looking to optimize this range we're also trying to weed out any duplicate codes created over time in our product database

How would you calculate the number of variants for a product given the following variations

1. Wattage - $6$ different wattage  (e.g. $18$ W, $25$ W, $30$ W, $35$ W, $40$ W, $45$ W)
2. Body Color - $3$ different colors ( e.g Black, White, Silver)
3. Color Temperature - $3$ different color temperatures ($2700$ K, $4000$ K, $5600$ K)
4. Beam Angle - $3$ different beam angles (Narrow, Medium, Wide)

Is it appropriate to use factorials to solve the above? Please help me.

Regards,

Vijay

Comment: Use the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jaap.